# Update based on the results of previous update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

We had a requirement to update price values in the Orders table based on the productids from the Products table. This is simple:

```
update o
set o.price = p.price
from Orders o 
inner join Products p
on o.productid = p.productid
```

Then the ask was to update the price from a different table (OrderPricing) based on a different column (orderpricingid) for the orders that were *not updated by the previous query*.

So I have another update statement:

```
update o
set o.price = op.price
from Orders o 
inner join OrderPricing op
on o.orderpricingid = p.orderpricingid
where o.price is null
```

So my question is - can the two update statements be combined together? Is there a way to update based on the results of the previous update query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both in the same query, if you change the joins from `inner` to `left`, using `coalesce`:

```
update o
set o.price = coalesce(p.price, op.price, o.price)
from Orders o 
left join Products p on o.productid = p.productid
left join OrderPricing op on o.orderpricingid = p.orderpricingid
```

This will update the price from the `products` table if the product exists there, if not, it will use the price from the `OrderPricing` table, but if that also don't exists it will just keep the original price.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution to my problem. Will check for performance... the table in question has around a million records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, as if o.price is null then you will update from order price so we can use `case when` in time of update

```
update o
set o.price= case when p.price is null then op.price else p.price end
from Orders o 
inner join Products p
on o.productid = p.productid
inner join OrderPricing op
on o.orderpricingid = p.orderpricingid
```

Comment: Will `o.price is null` work, because the update hasn't happened yet right?

Comment: as if o.price is null then you will update from order price so we can use case when in time of update

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a `left join`:

```
update o
    set o.price = coalesce(p.price, op.price)
from Orders o left join
     Products p
     on o.productid = p.productid left join
     OrderPricing op
     on o.orderpricingid = p.orderpricingid;
```